# PHP $_GET['something'] equivalent in C#

Tags: c#, php

I am new at C#, but i work in PHP, i need help for some equivalent PHP code to C# here is my code

```
if(isset($_GET['something'] == 'today')) {

    $test = $_GET['something'];
} else {
    $test = '';
}
```

How is possible to write that in C#?

Comment: We do not work in php and we do not know what is this. You must ask what you want in C# rather than giving your php code.

Comment: Nice but i dont ask you if you dont know, i asked if someone knows

Comment: Since you have PHP in your mind but try to work in ASP.NET MVC which has different concepts, you should really have some basic lessons at http://www.asp.net/mvc

Comment: Yup bro, But this will decrease the probability of Getting a good answer.

Comment: @Rohit But there are some developers that work in both Php and C# like myself. I guess he didn't just ask the right way.

Comment: Please read my previous comment @Oluwafemi. Thanks.

Comment: SO is not a language-transformation-service, just read some basics on ASP and you´lll get what you want very soon.

Comment: In response to your comment on Oluwafemi's answer, you are getting downvotes because your question (free labor request) does not show any research/effort at all. The syntax shown here in php is almost equivalent to what C# would use so its almost a direct translation, for the small part that isn't translated, you can easily find on google. Please read [ask]

Comment: I tried it to make so simple that everybody can understand, i dont know what does means Request.QueryString

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[**Request.QueryString**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms524784(v=vs.90).aspx) is equivalent to [**PHP's $_GET**](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.get.php) in C#. The QueryString collection retrieves the values of the variables in the HTTP query string.

```
string test = Request.QueryString["something"];
        if (test == "today")
        {
            // we've got test logic
        }
        else
        {
           test = string.Empty;
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

`$_GET` in php is just server side variable.

In ASP.NET MVC you have 3 rigth places where you can store and get this variables:

`ViewData` - Dictiorary

`ViewData.Model` - Strongly Typed and the **most right way**

`ViewBag` - `Dynamic` type storrage.

Also, you can get this params from `HttpContext.Request.QueryString` like this:

```
HttpContext.Request.QueryString["something"]
```

**But you should never do it in ASP.NET MVC.**

Comment: Mate $_get can also be contoller action, but i have so simple app that i dont need action for this

Answer (score -1):

ASP.NET MVC just doesn't work like this, if you have to write such a if-clause in ASP.NET MVC you don't understand it.

Basically, you would have some "action" like `public ActionResult Index(string something == "today") { ... }` where you can easily check the variable etc. it will be automatically fetched from your "routes" and http request context.

There are many good learning resources at http://www.asp.net/mvc like free Learning Videos from Pluralsight.

Comment: Mate PHP also can be MVC, it is also Controller Action,  but for my app i dont need that, i dont know why you are trying to explain me what is controller action, I didnt asked that :(

Comment: @play2web because it's the way ASP.NET MVC is designed, as I show you in the Example, the Variable is automatically resolved from the "Request.QueryString" when using something as simple as a Controller Action. And if you don't have Controller Actions, you obviously don't do ASP:NET MVC, but at time of my responsed, you had that as a Tag in your question